# jQuery fade in/out toggle method

Tags: jquery, toggle, fade, fadein, fadeout

I am having trouble with an `if / else` statement for fading in and out using a toggle link. I can get the `<div>` to fade in, however, I can not seem to get it to fade out. I am somewhat new to `if` and `else` statements.

[You can see a live demo here.](http://www.allaboutlsquared.com/index_fadein.html)

Here is the script in question:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    function toggleFader() {
    if ($("#fade_content").is(":hidden")) {
        $("#contentThatFades").animate(
            {
                opacity: "0"    
            },
            600,
            function(){
                $("#fade_content").fadeOut();
            }
        );
    }
    else {
        $("#fade_content").fadeIn(600, function(){
            $("#contentThatFades").animate(
                {
                    opacity: "1"
                },
                600
            );
        });
    }
}


</script>
```

Answer (score 16):

jQuery already has a function for this. See http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/

then you can simply do this:

```
$("#fade_content").fadeToggle(600);
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use `fadeToggle()`?

```
function toggleFader() {
    $("#fade_content").fadeToggle(600);
}
```